# How to pass array of data between UIViewControllers from @objc function

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Child `UICollectionViewController` where I have an array of images.
When I delete any photo I want to send back that array of updated images to Parent `UIViewController`.
Also in Child controller I have a programatically `view` which is called when I click on any image to expand it. When the image is expanded the user can click on a Delete button to delete photos from that array.
My array is updated correctly after delete but I can't manage to send it back to parent for some reasons.
I tried to send it back using Delegates and Protocols.
Here is my code for child controller:

```
protocol ListImagesDelegate {

    func receiveImagesUpdated(data: [String]?)
}

class ListImagesVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

// Properties
    var receivedImagesPath: [String]? = []
    var fullscreenImageView = UIImageView()
    var indexOfSelectedImage = 0
    var imagesAfterDelete: [String]? = []
    var delegate: ListImagesDefectDelegate?


override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        print("imagesAfterDelete: \(imagesAfterDelete ?? [])") // I'm getting the right number of images in this array.

        delegate?.receiveImagesUpdated(data: imagesAfterDelete)
    }


...
...

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("Click on photo: \(indexPath.item + 1)")

        if let imagePath = receivedImagesPath?[indexPath.item] {

            guard let selectedImage = loadImageFromDiskWith(fileName: imagePath) else {return}

            setupFullscreenImageView(image: selectedImage)

            indexOfSelectedImage = indexPath.item
        }
    }

    private func setupFullscreenImageView(image: UIImage){

        fullscreenImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        fullscreenImageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        fullscreenImageView.backgroundColor = .black
        fullscreenImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        fullscreenImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        self.view.addSubview(fullscreenImageView)
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

        let deleteButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: fullscreenImageView.bounds.maxX - 50, y: fullscreenImageView.bounds.maxY - 75, width: 30, height: 40))
        deleteButton.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]
        deleteButton.backgroundColor = .black
        deleteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "trashIcon"), for: .normal)
        deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        fullscreenImageView.addSubview(deleteButton)
    }

    @objc func deleteButtonTapped(button: UIButton!) {
        print("Delete button tapped")

        receivedImagesPath?.remove(at: indexOfSelectedImage)

        imagesAfterDelete = receivedImagesPath

        collectionView.reloadData()

        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
        fullscreenImageView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Here is the Parent controller:

```
var updatedImages: [String]? = []

...
...

extension NewAlbumVC: ListImagesDelegate {

    func receiveImagesUpdated(data: [String]?) {

        print("New array: \(data ?? [])") // This print is never called.

        updatedImages = data

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "goToImages" {

            let listImagesVC = segue.destination as! ListImagesVC

            listImagesVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

I want to specify that my child controller have set a Storyboard ID (`"ListImagesID"`) and also a segue identifier from parent to child (`"goToImages"`). Can cause this any conflict ?

Thanks if you read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the delegate is `nil` here

```
delegate?.receiveImagesUpdated(data: imagesAfterDelete)
```

For this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
```

to trigger you must have

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"goToImages",sender:nil)
```

---

**Edit:** This

```
let listImagesDefectVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListImagesDefectID") as!     ListImagesDefectVC
listImagesDefectVC.receivedImagesPath = imagesPath   
navigationController?.pushViewController(listImagesDefectVC, animated: true)
```

doesn't trigger `prepareForSegue` , so add

```
listImagesDefectV.delegate = self
```

So finally

**Solution 1 :**

```
@objc func tapOnImageView() { 
     let listImagesDefectVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListImagesDefectID") as! ListImagesDefectVC
     listImagesDefectVC.receivedImagesPath = imagesPath 
     listImagesDefectVC.delegate = self
     navigationController?.pushViewController(listImagesDefectVC, animated: true)
 }
```

**Solution 2 :**

```
 @objc func tapOnImageView() {  
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"goToImages",sender:nil) 
 }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "goToImages" {

        let listImagesVC = segue.destination as! ListImagesVC
        listImagesVC.receivedImagesPath = imagesPath 
        listImagesVC.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: I added `self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"goToImages",sender:nil)` in my prepare function but the same issue, is not triggering. I don't know what can be the reason.

Comment: put `performSegue`  inside the action that causes the move such as a button action

Comment: I did and the same issue. Here is my function which close the view and is returning to the parent VC:

    `@objc func deleteButtonTapped(button: UIButton!) {
        
        receivedImagesPath?.remove(at: indexOfSelectedImage)
        imagesAfterDelete = receivedImagesPath
        collectionView.reloadData()
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToImages", sender: nil)
        fullscreenImageView.removeFromSuperview()
    }`

Comment: When I click on an ImageView in the Parent VC I will navigate to the ListOfImages:

`@objc func tapOnImageView() {
        
        let listImagesDefectVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListImagesDefectID") as! ListImagesDefectVC
        
        listImagesDefectVC.receivedImagesPath = imagesPath
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(listImagesDefectVC, animated: true)
    }`

Comment: completely use `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToImages", sender: nil)` inside `tapOnImageView` or do what in edit  >>>>>> putting it in `deleteButtonTapped` is completely irrelevant ]<<<<<<

Comment: I did exactly how you teach me and now when I tap on that ImageView my collection view is empty:

`@objc func tapOnImageView() {
        
        let listImagesDefectVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListImagesDefectID") as! ListImagesDefectVC
        
        listImagesDefectVC.receivedImagesPath = imagesPath
        
        listImagesDefectVC.delegate = self
        
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"goToImagesDefects",sender:nil)
    }`

Comment: shouldn't  `"ListImagesDefectID") as! ListImagesDefectVC` be `as! ListImagesVC` as?

Comment: as a general rule when you do a navigation either use `navigationController?.pushViewController` or `performSegue`  btw you can also do a `present`

Comment: Is still not triggering my `protocol` function. I implemented both solutions. None of them worked for me. I don't know what I miss. :(

Comment: I'm stupid. I deleted the trigger protocol function by mistake: `delegate?.receiveImagesUpdated(data: imagesAfterDelete)`